# Wants to pass a parameter in servlet "www.blogger.com" but, it's change in servlet, to "http://www.blogger.comâ"

Tags: java, servlets

I created a servlet named "Op" and I sent a parameter named "link" using 
`href="Op?link=http://www.blogger.com"`. 
When I print the parameter in servlet, it shows `http://www.blogger.comâ`. How can I fix it? I'm using glassfish server, localhost.

Comment: You have escape your parameters in the URL properly.

Comment: Please show the relevant code.